# Fatal error: Cannot break/continue 1 level in

Tags: php

I have a function which must check basic auth setted credentials, if user exist in file .htgroup and check their password from file .htpasswd and return 0 if no matches 1 if matches.

```
$password = isset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW']) ? $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW'] : '';
$user = isset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']) ? $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'] : '';

function authenticate($user, $password) {

    $AuthUserFile = file(".htpasswd");
    $AuthGroupFile = file(".htgroup");
    $group = "Members";

        if(!preg_grep("/$group: $user$/", $AuthGroupFile)) {
            if(!($authUserLine = array_shift(preg_grep("/$user:.*$/", $AuthUserFile)))) {
                preg_match("/$user:((..).*)$/", $authUserLine, $matches);
                $authPW = $matches[1];
                $salt = $matches[2];

                $submittedPW = crypt($password, $salt);
                if($submittedPW != $authPW) { return 0; } else { return 1; };
            } else { return 0; };
        }else { return 0; };

}
```

I got error on `if(!($authUserLine = array_shift(preg_grep("/$user:.*$/", $AuthUserFile)))) {`

```
Strict Standards: Only variables should be passed by reference in /var/www/auth.php on line 54
```

What is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**array_shift** needs to have the first argument passed as reference as it needs to updated the array you pass and remove the first element.

In order to make it work, you'll need to store the result of **preg_grep** in a variable:

```
$matches = preg_grep("/$user:.*$/", $AuthUserFile);
if(!($authUserLine = array_shift($matches))) {
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As from [PHP.net](http://bd.php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php) documentation following things can be passed by reference:

> 1. Variables, i.e. foo($a)
> 2. New statements, i.e. foo(new foobar())
> 3. References returned from functions

No other expressions should be passed by reference, as the result is 
undefined. For example, the following examples of passing by reference 
are invalid.

`array_shift` is the only parameter is an array passed by reference. The return value of `$AuthGroupFile` does not have any reference. Hence the error. You should store the produced value of `preg_grep("/$user:.*$/", $AuthUserFile);` to `$pregGrap` a variable first. After that use `array_sift()` for referencing.

Final code is like :

```
if(!($authUserLine = array_shift(preg_grep("/$user:.*$/", $AuthUserFile)))) {}
```

If you're not passing a variable in then there's nothing for a reference to point to.

Thanks!